# How to give a role to all members, with a interval

Tags: discord.js

I want to make a command so i can give all the users in my discord server a role.

Problem is now with the code i have, that he gives not all the members the specified role because it are to much members and it will spam the discord api.

How can i make it so that after i do the command, the bot will give all the members the specified role, but not directly to prevent spamming the API, but for example every 10 min he gives 5 members the role until all the members got the role.

Hope some one could helpe me

this is what i have now :

````
module.exports = {
    name: "give-roles",
    aliases: ["gr"],
    category: "roles",
    description: "Give's all members the Verified-Member role",
    usage: `${prefix}give-roles`,

    run: async (Client, message) => {


          message.guild.members.fetch()
          .then(console.log)
             .catch(console.error);

  
     let role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === 'Verified-Member')

     if (!role) return message.channel.send(`**${message.author.username}**, role not found`)

          
            message.guild.members.cache.filter(m => !m.user.bot).forEach(member => member.roles.add(role))            
            message.channel.send(`**${message.author.username}**, role **${role.name}** was added to all members`)
            
    },
  }```
````

Answer (score 0):

A way to get round this is to add a role when a member joins instead of all at once (which will never work since not all members will be cached)

```js
<client>.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
  var memberRole = member.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "<role name here>");
  member.roles.add(memberRole); //auto assign role on join
});
```

> **change the code in `<>` to fit your needs**

The reason you cannot add a role to all members is due to the v12 addition of cache.

**Managers/Cache**

> v12 introduces the concept of managers, you will no longer be able to directly use collection methods such as Collection#get on data structures like Client#users. You will now have to directly ask for cache on a manager before trying to use collection methods. Any method that is called directly on a manager will call the API, such as GuildMemberManager#fetch and MessageManager#delete.

I would recommend that you read the docs to further understanding of how bots work [here](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v12.html#commonly-used-methods-that-changed)

Comment: I have already a bot that gives the new members the role, but for all the members that are already in the guild they need this role, so i wanted to make this very simpel i just need to give them only once this role